# OrWhere statement Doctrine 1

Tags: doctrine

SOLVED the problem with a single andWhere statement

```
$query->andWhere("(SELECT COUNT(*) as result FROM EvaluateurCandidature ec4 WHERE ec.candidature_id_ca = ec4.candidature_id_ca AND ec4.role_evaluateur = 'rapporteur' AND ec4.statut_evaluation = ? OR ec.candidature_id_ca = ec4.candidature_id_ca AND ec4.role_evaluateur = 'rapporteur' AND ec4.statut_evaluation = ? ) >= '2'" , array('en cours' , 'terminée'));
```

I try to make an OrWhere statement in my query but when i'm doing this, it's return me objects who are not depending on c.id_ap.

Someone know how i could achieve the query with the orWhere in a single line maybe ? I tried this without success

> $query->andWhere("(SELECT COUNT(*) as result FROM EvaluateurCandidature ec2 WHERE ec.candidature_id_ca = ec2.candidature_id_ca AND ec2.role_evaluateur = 'evaluateur' AND ec2.statut_evaluation = 'en cours' OR ec2.statut_evaluation = 'terminée') >= '2'");

I just need to check if there is more than 2 results in ec2.statut_evaluation = 'en cours' or 'terminée'

Here the actual query :

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Candidature c')
            ->leftJoin('c.EvaluateurCandidature ec')
            ->where('c.id_stca = 5');

 $query->andWhere('c.id_ap=?', array($this->id_ap));

      $query->andWhere("(SELECT COUNT(*) as result FROM EvaluateurCandidature ec2 WHERE ec.candidature_id_ca = ec2.candidature_id_ca AND ec2.role_evaluateur = 'evaluateur' AND ec2.statut_evaluation = 'en cours') >= '2'");

      $query->orWhere("(SELECT COUNT(*) as result FROM EvaluateurCandidature ec3 WHERE ec.candidature_id_ca = ec3.candidature_id_ca AND ec3.role_evaluateur = 'evaluateur' AND ec3.statut_evaluation = 'terminée') >= '2'");
```

Answer (score 0):

For your issue you need to group your `OR` criteria to avoid such issue, this is because of operator precedence, `AND` binds before `OR`,So your query is evaluated  as

```
c.id_stca = some AND  (SELECT ...) >= 2 OR (SELECT ...) >= 2
```

It should be grouped as

```
c.id_stca = some AND ( (SELECT ...) >= 2 OR (SELECT ...) >= 2 )
```

For doctrine 1 i guess n query builder you could write it as

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Candidature c')
            ->leftJoin('c.EvaluateurCandidature ec')
            ->where('c.id_stca = 5')
            ->andWhere('c.id_ap=?', array($this->id_ap))
            ->andWhere( 
                $query->expr()->orX(
                    $query->andWhere("(SELECT COUNT(*) as result 
                                       FROM EvaluateurCandidature ec2 
                                       WHERE ec.candidature_id_ca = ec2.candidature_id_ca 
                                       AND ec2.role_evaluateur = 'evaluateur' 
                                       AND ec2.statut_evaluation = 'en cours') >= '2'"),
                    $query->andWhere("(SELECT COUNT(*) as result 
                                       FROM EvaluateurCandidature ec3 
                                       WHERE ec.candidature_id_ca = ec3.candidature_id_ca 
                                       AND ec3.role_evaluateur = 'evaluateur' 
                                       AND ec3.statut_evaluation = 'terminée') >= '2'")
                )
            );
```